# How can I properly paste a data in lets say in tab 'Test', starting cell B3, all at once?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm having a data, let's say 10 lines, each has 10 cells (columns), can I paste all data at once starting let's say cell C8, nicely, each line. So it would be 
C8 to C18 - then
D8 to D18 ... etc.

That's what I've used so far:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(lConnection), Destination:=Range("A5"))
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = lRequete
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .FieldNames = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
    .MaintainConnection = False
    .Delete
End With
```

And it errors at this line `.CommandType = xlCmdSql`saying: 
*Argument or call of the procedure is incorrect*

Any better solution?

**UPDATE:**
.Refresh Error
*Error '1004'*
*Source of the data is incomplet*

Comment: Do you try to copy paste? Is it coming any error or warning?

Comment: What code did you try? Are you getting errors? Or are you lazy and you just want a solution?

Comment: Loool!
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(lConnection), Destination:=Range("A5"))
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = lRequete
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .FieldNames = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
    .MaintainConnection = False
    .Delete
End With

I've tried this, but getting an error. Something is wrong with 'xlCmdSql'

Comment: Why are you using a querytable instead of copy/paste?

Comment: Can someone tell Alex (and me by implication :-)) how to mark code in a comment?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code -- very hard to see when it is in a comment due to formatting.  Also show the kind of error and the exact point in the code where it occurs.  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BobPhillips You can't really post more than a single line of code in a comment and hope to have it show intelligently. You can set off that line with single backticks `ASCII Code 96` .  For more info, see this article on [Code Comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: You have sql tagged. Are you pulling data from a database? Please show ADO/DAO connection string.

Comment: `lConnection = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=SERVER; Database=TEST; User Id=sa; Password=*****;"`

Comment: `lRequete = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CODE = '42882' and DATE BETWEEN '01/02/2010' AND '01/02/2011'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string seemed to be a problem.
replaced **this**
`"Driver={SQL Server}; Server=X; Database=X; User Id=sa; Password=******;"`

 **to this**
`"ODBC;SERVER=X;DSN=X;DATABASE=X;Trusted_Connection=Yes"`